# Connection Pool - OJDBC5 increased sessions

Tags: java, connection-pooling, ojdbc

What is the usual trigger for connection pools to increase/decrease in sessions? I can not for the life of me track where I can improve my connection pool handling. As I cannot find any documentation and/or source code for ojdcb5.jar to read up and explore. I just want to find the trigger so i can fully understand what is happening to my application.

Background: Java application uses ojdbc5.jar to connect to oracle 11g (11.2.0.3).
Sometimes the application increases the number of connections in the middle of the day but it isn't even in peak hours. minimum number of connections is 10 but the average is 20 and max is 200.

And on other times it reduces the number of sessions. which sometimes makes my application crash because the number of connections is lower than the supply in the pool.

I don't know what triggers the reduction/addition of sessions. Any ideas?

Comment: Which connection pool are you using? What is the environment you run it in? (Tomcat? Wildfly? TomEE? Jetty?) How did you configure the connection pool? (In the Java code? Through a JNDI configuration? Through the application server's UIT?)

Comment: The documentation of Oracle's JDBC driver is part of the Oracle manuals: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/toc.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 

    
Which connection pool are you using? Hmm im not sure. i just use oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource in java. Does that answer your question? sorry im not so familiar with the connection pool libraries.


What is the environment you run it in? 
It runs as a standalone app in a linux server connected to Oracle DB.


How did you configure the connection pool? 
it is integrated within the java code.